# Can't type inside a textarea after tabbing to its containing div?

Tags: jquery

Can't type inside the textarea after tabbing to its (id="center") containing div?

Here is the code...

```
 <div id="north">North</div>
 <div id="west">West</div>
 <div id="center"><textarea></textarea></div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divs = ["north", "west", "center"];
    var startIndex = 0;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 9) {
            $("div").css("border", "");
            $("#" + divs[startIndex]).css("border", "4px solid gray");
            startIndex++;
            if (startIndex === divs.length) {
                startIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: You have all keydown's returning false except for one.. that's why

Comment: Thanks Wirey, so how do I fix it?

Comment: remove the return false.. that should fix it

Comment: it works but it tabs to the url of the browser but the return false prevents it from tabbing to the url of the browser

Comment: Then you need to include it inside the if statement - to confine it only to the tab button.. so move it before the previous closing bracket

Comment: Someone posted a working solution but its removed now and that I had to relocation the return false statement inside the if condition. Its working now.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning false on ever keydown - which is preventing you from typing inside your textarea

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        $("div").css("border", "");
        $("#" + divs[startIndex]).css("border", "4px solid gray");
        startIndex++;
        if (startIndex === divs.length) {
            startIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    return false; // <--
});
```

If you want to prevent default tab behavior you should move it inside the `if (e.which == 9)` statement

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        $("div").css("border", "");
        $("#" + divs[startIndex]).css("border", "4px solid gray");
        startIndex++;
        if (startIndex === divs.length) {
            startIndex = 0;
        }
        return false; // <-- Move it here to prevent tab default behavior
    }        
});
```

Or you can remove it altogether if you don't need to prevent any default behavior on keydown

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.preventDefault()` method to stop the default event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divs = ["north", "west", "center"];
    var startIndex = 0;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 9) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $("div").css("border", "");
            $("#" + divs[startIndex]).css("border", "4px solid gray");
            startIndex++;
            if (startIndex === divs.length) {
                startIndex = 0;
            }
        }

    });
});
```